# Rolling up multiple varbinary(max) rows into a single row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, aggregate, varbinary

My table looks something like this:

| BinFiles |
| --- |
| 0x1101ABB1C... |
| 0x2202DEE2F... |
| 0x3303GHH3I... |

I tried this to get a single line:

```
SELECT
    STUFF((SELECT d.BinFiles
    FROM dbo.demo d
    WHERE d.ID = dd.ID
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') BinFiles
FROM
    dbo.demo dd
```

How can I do this? Or is this possible for varbinary data (size issues)?

I'm using SQLServer 2019. The varbinary columns are part of a pdf file (1Mb per file). I need to join these columns into a single row for export again as a pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with this query. If you have many 'bin' files that are part of one file you can try this:

```
DECLARE @concatData varbinary(max),@FileName varchar(255)
SELECT @concatData = COALESCE(@concatData, 0x) + BinFiles,@FileName=FileName
FROM test.dbo.demo2
ORDER BY RowNum

select @concatData as BinFiles,@FileName as FileName
```